# UpdateCommand not work

Tags: c#, ado.net, sqlclient

I have the following code. Both inserting and deleting work except the update. I used SQL Server profiler to trace it and find that no SQL is issued for updating. I tested with `dt.Rows[0].RowState` with value of "Modified".

```
using(var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        con.Open();
        var da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from table", con);
        var cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
        cb.ConflictOption = ConflictOption.OverwriteChanges;

        da.UpdateCommand = cb.GetUpdateCommand();
        da.InsertCommand = cb.GetInsertCommand();
        da.DeleteCommand = cb.GetDeleteCommand();
        da.UpdateBatchSize = 2000;
        da.Update(dt);
    }
    scope.Complete();
}
```

Comment: did you check that the generated update sql command looks ok?

Comment: The update SQL is ok if I trace line by line on the method. It was `update table where Id = @p1` if I set breakpoint at the last line in the block. There is no error/exception.

Comment: your update command should look like this: UPDATE [table] SET [x] = \@p1, [y] = \@p2 WHERE [x] = \@p3 ... without SET it can't work ...

Comment: I know. Strangely the debugger showed two different results. And there is no error.